# Is there something like std::remove_const_reference in type_traits

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, type-traits

There ale some functions in std C++ library that are able to modify types, like `std::remove_reference` or `std::remove_cv`. I wonder if/why not there is something like `std::remove_const_reference`, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using remove_cref_t = typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

template <typename T>
void linker_test_type();

int main() {
    using type = int volatile const&;
    test<remove_cref_t<type>>();
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is of course:

```
undefined reference to `void linker_test_type<int volatile>()'
```

Comment: Look: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay

Comment: You might already compose them, and std doesn't provide all combination.

Comment: "why not there is something like `std::remove_const_reference`?" My guess: Because it's a one-liner anyone can write themselves (just as you did in the Q). If we start providing combinations, where to stop?

Comment: @Angew I think we could stop before `remove_cv` but we didn't. But you are probably right.

Comment: @jaskmar `cv` is on the same "axis" as `const` and `volatile`. `const` and `reference` are on different "axes".

Comment: The situation where I'd want to remove c and r but not v seem extremely unusual to me.  Then again, volatile always seemed like an underspecified mess, so using it seems unusual to me all by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned this in [std-proposals two years ago](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/lJqeyyBI6W4). And to be honest, I don't think the occasional use case warrants inclusion in the standard when we can construct this trait by composing two others. We could think of many useful traits, but only fundamental building blocks should be provided, or we run risk of polluting the library with traits we cannot all remember (which is kinda useless).

Comment: Walter Brown recently proposed `uncvref`. There's enough common use cases for that that it's worth standardizing, IMO. But separate `const` and `volatile` versions is definitely overkill.